# HASH element from an object's return in a single string

Tags: perl, function, object, hash, module

I have a module **Module.pm** with function `getHash()` which returns, as you guessed, a hash of data)). We all know well how to get an element form that hash, using a standard model:

```
use Module;
my $m = new Module;
my %hash = $m->getHash();
print $hash{needed_element's_key};
```

everything is ok.
But what if you need to write two last strings in a single string **WITHOUT** initializing a new HASH (and occupying a memory for a whole hash, using just one element)?

Is it possible to do so somehow? Like, say, `$m->getHash()->{needed_element's_key};`
Of course, the given example does not work.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to return a hash. Subs can only return a list of scalars. You are assigning that list of scalars to an existing hash `my %hash` and getting an element of that hash.

You could disguise the fact that you are creating a new hash by using an anonymous hash:

```
my $val = { $m->getKeyValPairs() }->{$key};
```

Alternatively, a custom filter could be more efficient:

```
sub find_val {
   my $target_key = shift;
   while (@_) {
      my $key = shift;
      my $val = shift;
      return $val if $key eq $target_key;
   }

   return undef;
}

my $val = find_val $key, $m->getKeyValPairs();
```

But the best option would be to have the method return a reference to a hash instead. Then, you wouldn't have to perform the wasteful activity of creating a hash. You'd simply use the following:

```
$m->getHashRef()->{$key}
```

Comment: `return;` or `return ();` may be a better choice, and custom filter could be more efficient only for *very* large hashes?

Comment: @Сухой27, We're approximating `$hash{$key}`, so I used the same semantics as `$hash{$key}`. Well, if the filter was written in XS, it would always be more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

If a sub does `return %hash`, it actually returns a list of keys and values (alternating).  You can put it back in a hash and get a specific key with:

```
print +{ $m->getHash() }->{needed_element_key};
```

(The leading `+` is needed to prevent perl from thinking the `{` is a block returning a filehandle to print to.)

But you are better off just returning a hash reference.

Comment: Thanks! I've just replaced a return with a reference and it works and moreover looks great now! Thanks!